# How to set 1min interval time logic in java

Tags: java, time

I am stuck on one problem: I want to send a useraccountname and password via mail, but with a 1 minute interval between. That is, the useraccountname should go be sent first via mail, and  after a 1 minute interval should be sent too.

How do I implement the logic for this 1 minute interval in Java?

Comment: Is your problem got resolved?

Comment: @Naman Gala: Yes sir!!

Comment: Can you please provide how your problem got solved?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ScheduledExecutorService`. This allows you to queue up tasks with given time intervals.

**Example**

You create a `Runnable`..

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { System.out.println("Do something!"); }
}

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate() // I won't tell you how to do this!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the thread to wait if it's not multithread:

```
 Thread.sleep(60000);
```